# valued stored in multiprocessing Value is not the same as the original

Tags: multiprocessing, ctypes

I am trying to store a bytes object inside of the multiprocessing class Value but I found that the value actually stored and the value I wanted to store are different. As an example the following code evaluates to False.

```
import ctypes
import dill
import multiprocessing as mp
x = [{str(i):i} for i in range(10)]

y = dill.dumps(x)

serialized_workbook = mp.Value(ctypes.c_char_p, dill.dumps(None))
serialized_workbook.value = y
serialized_workbook.value ==  y
```

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it from happening? The reason I want to do this is so that I can later load it again.

```
dill.loads(serialized_workbook.value)
```

The above fails while the following piece of code does not.

```
dill.loads(y)
```

Comment: The `value` of a `c_char_p` is a null-terminated string, so it stops at the first null in the `dumps(x)` string. Also, since `c_char_p` is a pointer, it's generally useless in a cross-platform multiprocessing context. Windows doesn't have `fork` to share the address space of the parent process, so sharing a pointer with another process is meaningless (within the `multiprocessing` framework). You can use a [`multiprocessing.Array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array) with type `c_char` or `c_ubyte`.

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. I understand more of the problem now but I am constantly modifying the contents of serialized_worbook and this variable needs to be accessed across different processes which makes me think i should use mp.Manager to get a shared list. I do not have objections to this upfront. Any comments on this?

Comment: Using `mmap` backed shared memory via `Value` and `Array` has the benefit of not having to pickle and pipe data between processes. Otherwise sharing state across processes is a performance bottleneck. Generally it's best to keep worker processes as stateless as possible. Pass messages to workers via a `Pipe` or `Queue`. A process `Pool` is a simple way to manage this. A work item should generally be CPU bound. For I/O bound work, it's generally better to use threads, or an asynchronous I/O framework with coroutines.

Comment: In other words, you need to put a lot of thought into the application architecture before writing any code. Use coroutines/threads and processes where appropriate. If you need multiprocessing to access multiple cores for a CPU bound problem, carefully design the system to avoid sharing state between processes. If you absolutely must share state, and shared memory isn't an option, then a managed container is appropriate. That's what it's there for. But it comes at a tangible cost in terms of synchronization and data copying.